# MongoDB :Auth mechanism not specified Error for specific Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, web, web-applications

We running 2 web .net project on same Pc and connecting  to same Mongod server .
first and second project connect to same database.

First project with authorization connection string working fine without connection issue
but Second project with same authorization string giving Auth mechanism not specified error
if I specified any auth mechanism then it giving
Unsupported MongoAuthenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1 error

This is happen only for second project , not issue with first project
I am sure that

1. both mongod server and shell version match
2. same connection string for both

but why it giving issue  for second project only. what would be possible project level issue? any idea.

Please help for this

Comment: If both apps are on the same host and trying to connect to the same database with the same connection string and one app will succeed where the other will fail there must be something different in your application code (the app that failed).

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue, MongoDb DLL issue which is different for both projected. Used one which is working for both.